# can you have static and instance methods in the same c# or c++ class ?

Tags: c#, c++, static, static-methods

Can you have static and instance methods in the same c# or c++ class ?
If yes, what would be the use of having both, if no why not ?

Comment: Can you give a *specific* example, with code? And, please limit your question to one language. C# and C++ are quite different.

Comment: Look at the String class of the framework...and you will get the answer to both questions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course you can!

Static methods do not pass an implicit `this` pointer and are used whenever you do not need to operate on a specific instance of that class/type (such as modifying its members).

If you *do* need to modify a specific instance, you should use an instance method.

There's no reason that these two types of methods cannot be declared together in the same class. If you're using C#, check out some of the classes defined by the .NET Framework. Lots of them have both static and instance methods. That will give you some idea as to how these might be used effectively.

In C++, there's no reason to even create a "static" class (one with all static methods) as you might find in C#. The better approach would be to put the functions into a namespace as free functions. Not everything has to be an "object".

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

And lots of uses. Static methods are usually library tools, which can be applied on instances of the class.

Instance methods are methods that you invoke by each specific instance.

Comment: Thank you all. Not homework now, but yes I am just learning this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here's a practicle example from the framework itself:

```
namespace System
{
    public struct Int32 //...
    {
        public const int MaxValue = 2147483647;

        //...

        public TypeCode GetTypeCode();
        public static int Parse(string s);

        //...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only those members are kept Static that are needed to be shared though each and every object of the same origin class equally, for instance if you have a static method (static method also requires to return a static value of the class), static members are initiated before even you make an object of that class.

now you also asked why and why not, remember there are thousand ways of doing so and thousand reasons if you start thinking in Object-Oriented manner.